# How to enable shading in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do you enable shading in Three.js?

Various examples have shown it should be as simple as assigning THREE.FlatShading to your material, but when I do this, my shape has no shading at all.

My JS:

```
CANVAS_WIDTH = 200,
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;
init();
animate();
function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 400;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
    material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
    for(var i=0; i<material.length; i++){
        material[i].shading = THREE.FlatShading;
    }

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    // light
    //scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ) );
    light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 400, 400, 400 );
    scene.add( light );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT );
    container = document.getElementById( 'accelgyro_canvas' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
function animate() {
console.log('animate')
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

And this renders by cube as:

[image]

I've tried adjusting the light angles, adding/removing ambient light, changing which object I add the FlatShading to and nothing seems to help.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you interested in shadows (as in http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shadowmap_viewer), or in shading (http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_materials_normal)? The title of the question doesn't match the contents

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[image: Flat Shading]

Are your looking for result like this.

Attaching the reference code for same

```
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0xffffff,1.0))


            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
            for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
            {

                geometry.faces[ i ].color.setRGB( 1.0 * Math.random()+0.2 , 0, 0 );     
            }
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0xff0000,vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors  } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            //mesh.drawMode =THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;
            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

`MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights.

Use `MeshLambertMaterial`, `MeshPhongMaterial`, `MeshStandardMaterial`, or `MeshPhysicalMaterial`.

three.js r.152

Comment: Makes sense except I don't see why this jsfiddle seems to have shading with MeshBasicMaterial ? http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/w67tzfhx/81/

Comment: @WillKessler That cube doesn't have shading. It's just that the cube's faces are painted different colors. I'm also trying to get my cube to shade :|